# Accessing clipboard data in Microsoft Edge giving "SCRIPT5: Access is denied" error

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am trying to access the clipboard data in Microsoft Edge in javascript. But when I access it I get an "SCRIPT5: Access is denied." error in the console.

This is the function in which I am trying to access the clipboard data.

```
function (e) {
                if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > 0) {
                    var clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;
                    if (clipboardData && clipboardData.items && clipboardData.items.length) {
                        var item = clipboardData.items[0];

                        if (item.kind === 'file' && item.type.indexOf('image/') !== -1) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            var blob = item.getAsFile();
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function (event) {
                                console.log(event.target.result);
                                $(_this).summernote('insertImage', event.target.result, 'image.png');
                            }; 
                            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                        }
                    }
```

From what I understand there are some security measures in Microosft Edge to disable malicious scripts from accessing your clipboard data.

Comment: It seems that you are using the Clipboard API, withe refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API), we can see that Edge browser not support the Clipboard API. You can also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113086/microsoft-edge-browser-how-to-read-clipboard-data).